# Mobile Android music playback

Tags: android, web, android-music-player

i have developed a mobile web app that plays back music everything work great apart from.

We i open the app and start playing music if i try and close the screen to put it in my pocket the music stops really annoying so i have to hold the app the whole time.

If i do try and put it in my pocket with the screen open a button normally gets clicked in my pocket and it goes of also annoying.

I know when developing for a ios app you can use allow background service.

Is there a way you can do this for a mobile web app.

I am using a Samsung s3 galaxy

Any suggestions thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have no way but create [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for your application. When you close Activity, Service continues to run

Comment: Hi Maxim thanks for the reply. So can you hook a android activity into a jquery web app somehow a bit confused?